# Angular Dialog changes are overwriting always the UI

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am passing data in an Angular dialog, but in meantime when I edit something in the Dialog it overwrites the data even I didn't save them.
For example I have an Object and I click ot edit it.
It opens an Angular Dialog with all data of this Object.

Is it possible only to change data when I click save button.
I heard about Object.assign it can be useful but didn't know how to use it.
I tried with `Object.assign` but it didn't work.
Why is not working I think that this.data holds another data as the this.data.education.
See the code below
This is my code of the dialog.

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: EditEducation,
              private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EducationDialogComponent>,
              public dataService: ModelDataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.data.edit) {
      this.data.education = {} as SubCategory;
    } else {
      ({education: this.data.education} = Object.assign({}, this.data));
    }
  }
```

And this is how I open the dialog.

```
  <ul>
    <li class="fa fa-pencil addIconTop" (click)="editEducation({edit: true, education: subCategory, model: model})"></li>
    <button (click)="addEducation({edit: false, model: model})" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-plus addIconBottom"></i></button>
    <button [disabled]="education.subCategories.length === 1" (click)="deleteSubCategory(i)" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash deleteIconRight"></i></button>
    <li class="fa fa-arrow-down moveIconDown"></li>
    <li class="fa fa-arrow-up moveIconTop"></li>
  </ul>

public editData(data: EditEducation) {
   this.dialog.open(DataDialogComponent, {
        data,
        });
  }
public addData(data: EditEducation) {
    this.dialog.open(DataDialogComponent, {
      data,
    });
  }
```

This is one interface to see if is one new Object or is need to be edited.

```
export interface EditEducation {
  education?: SubCategory;
  edit?: boolean;
  model?: Model;
}
```

This is the interface of `Education`

```
export interface Education {
  subCategories: EducationSubCategory[];
}


 export interface EducationSubCategory {
  name: string;
  startDate: number;
  endDate: number;
  graduation: string;
  title?: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Creating a copy is a good idea here. `this.data = Object.assign({}, data);` or `this.data = {...data};` are both solid alternatives if you only need a shallow copy. If you have nested arrays or objects, you will need to recursively copy. Make sure that the code that opens the dialog has access to the updated value after save if it wants.

Comment: I have tried that but didn't work.
I tried something like this.
`({education: this.data.education} = Object.assign({}, this.data));`

Comment: It "didn't work" is not something I can help with

Comment: @AluanHaddad i have edited my comment, it overwrites it again.
Do I need to make the copy in the dialog component or in the parent component ?

Comment: You could do it in either place. If in dialog, do it in constructor, where the value is injected.

Comment: A better approach, if the data has already been saved by your server, would be to have just pass the object's id to the dialog and have the dialog retrieve the data directly.

Comment: Yes the data are saved but it is only one ID for the whole Objects and Array it is declared at top of the interface like this.
`export interface Model {
  _id?: string;
  personalData?: PersonalData[];
  skills?: Skills[];
  education?: Education[];
  careers?: Carrier[];
  user?: string;
}`

Comment: Don't you have an endpoint for retrieving one of those objects by id on your backend? like `api/careers/5`?

Comment: Nope I do have only `api/data/1` and that's it for the whole Model
I get the whole api in one `get` I use `post` only once and `put` to update the main Model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221866/discussion-between-abedin-zhuniqi-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: Can't help with that. It's a design question based on your domain. It sounds awful in a general sense, but there are situations where it would be appropriate.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you for the time, but you are suggesting that need to be in every Object an ID ?

Comment: No. It depends on the semantics of your specific system. The answer is contextual

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you for the time and suggestions.
I tried with Object.assign and cloneDeep but it didn't work.
I am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Problem

You are experincing a case of variables being passed by reference

> Javascript has 5 primitive data types that are passed by value: `Boolean`, `null`, `undefined`, `String`, and `Number` 
> Variables that are assigned a non-primitive value are given a reference to that value. That reference points to the object’s location in memory. The variables don’t actually contain the value 
> When a reference type value, an object, is copied to another variable using =, the address of that value is what’s actually copied over as if it were a primitive. **Objects are copied by reference instead of by value**.

### Solution

The easiest way to solve the problem would be to use the spread operator **`(...)`** while assigning your variables. Below is a refactor of your code that should solve the problem

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: EditEducation,
              private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EducationDialogComponent>,
              public dataService: ModelDataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.data.edit) {
      this.data.education = {} as SubCategory;
    } else {
      ({education: this.data.education} = {...this.data };
    }
  }
```

```
public editData(data: EditEducation) {
   this.dialog.open(DataDialogComponent, { ...data});
  }
public addData(data: EditEducation) {
    this.dialog.open(DataDialogComponent, {...data});
  }
```

Comment: At the editData method I am facing with an error which is saying.
`TS2559: Type '{ education?: EducationSubCategory; edit?: boolean; model?: Model; }' has no properties in common with type 'MatDialogConfig '.`

Answer (score 1):

It is best to copy the object before sending it into the dialog. This way your original data stays unedited:

```
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DataDialogComponent, {
     data: _.cloneDeep(data),
   });
```

For the deep clone I suggest you use the [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) library. It has a function called "cloneDeep" which copies the object inclusive all nested objects.

In your `DataDialogComponent.ts` you can send the updated data back to the parent component through the DialogRef when you save the edits:

```
  save(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.data)
  }
```

In the parent component you can subscribe to the DialogRef and update the original data:

```
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((updatedData) => {
     if (updatedData) {
       this.data = updatedData;
     }
   });
```

### Complete Code

`ParentComponent.ts`

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from '../dialog/dialog.component';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Education;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  public editData(data: EditEducation) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DataDialogComponent, {
      data: _.cloneDeep(data),
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((updatedData) => {
      if (updatedData) {
        this.data = updatedData;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`DataDialogComponent.ts`

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export class DataDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: EditEducation,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DataDialogComponent>
  ) {}

  // Implement your methods

  save(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.data)
  }

  discard(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have one problem there and that is the declared `education:Education` at the parent component.
That interface has children as subCategories.
I will add the Interface of it.